# Why does taking the partial derivative of a stream function in the y-axis gives the flow velocity in the x-axis?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

New to fluid dynamics here.

I've been reading about stream functions from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function) wikipedia article and it states that:

[image: flow velocity in x-axis]

and

[image]

where u is the velocity in the x- axis and v is in the y-axis.

If it has something to do with the dot product of the flow velocity and the curve crossed by the streamlines, then why doesn't it work the other way? I thought dot products were scalars. I can't seem to understand why the partial derivative is taken with respect of the axis that is perpendicular to the flow velocity vector. What happens if we take the partial derivative with the axis corresponding with the flow vector? I couldn't wrap my head around the idea of this concept.

I also couldn't understand this statement that defines the stream function

> So the stream function $\psi$  is the volume flux through the curve $\
> AP$, that is: the integral of the dot product of the flow velocity
>   vector $\ (u,v)$ and the normal $(+\ dy,-\ dx)$ to the curve
>   element $(\ dx,\ dy)$.The point $\ A$ is a reference point defining
>   where the stream function is zero: a shift of $\ A$ results in adding
>   a constant to the stream function $\psi$ .

what does the stream function has to do with normals? isn't the stream function similar to the measure of flux (hence the article says it's the volume flux)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream function is specified in this way because it automatically satisfies the incompressible continuity equation.  This reduces the number of dependent variables from u and v to just psi, and eliminates one equation from the system.   Plus, the gradient of the stream function is parallel to the normal, and is equal in magnitude to the tangential velocity.  So the total volumetric flow rate across any line joining two spatial locations in the flow is equal to the difference in stream function between these two points.  Pretty powerful, huh!

Comment: Ooh i see it's now starting to make sense. I'd also like to ask about the last sentence however. The stream function in an incompressible fluid flow is known to be constant (according to what i understand from the article). Does that mean that the volumetric flow across the curve element in that flow is zero(no difference between the line)? Seems like that scenario isn't true and i can't understand why. Anyways thank you for your response.

Comment: The stream function is not constant for an incompressible flow, unless there is no flow at all.

Comment: I see that the stream function isn't constant, but why does the article states that "Since streamlines are tangent to the flow velocity vector of the flow, the value of the stream function must be constant along a streamline."? Am i missing something here?

Comment: Since a streamline is tangent to the velocity vector, along a stream line, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{v}{u}$$or $$udy-vdx=0$$or$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}dy=0$$But, the stream function is constant if $$d\psi=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}dy=0$$

Comment: That makes so much more sense! Thank you very much